# App Engine Localhost get rid of log message not a dispatchable path

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

In my dispatch.yaml file I have:

```
application: promptappointment

dispatch:

  # Send all work to the one static backend.
  - url: "*/work/*"
    module: static-backend

  # Default module serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
  - url: "*/*"
    module: default

  # Default module serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "promptappointment.appspot.com/"
    module: default

#  # Send all mobile traffic to the mobile frontend.
#  - url: "*/mobile/*"
#    module: mobile-frontend
```

When I run this I get the message:

```
Skipping dispatch.yaml rules because /_ah/channel/dev is not a dispatchable path.
```

I assume that's because the default path, but does anyone know how to fix this so I can get rid of that log message? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the paths to your default modules.  Your dispatch.yaml could just be

```
application: promptappointment

dispatch:

  # Send all work to the one static backend.
  - url: "*/work/*"
    module: static-backend
```

everything that doesn't match */work/* should automatically go to your default module.

I'm not certain that this will fix your log message though.

Comment: Some you're right I don't need that line and you're also right that doesn't solve the problem :-)

It seems to happen every time this is called:

http://localhost:8080/_ah/channel/dev